# How to convert variable type IntPtr to ToString in C#

Tags: c#, window, tostring, handle, typeconverter

I have a variable `IntPtr` with value, ex `IntPtr I` is `01x0712314`.

How I can show `"01x0712314"` of variable above to label, textbox or set value to variable string A in C#

I had try with `.ToString()`, `Int a = (int)I`. all value after convert from `01x0712314` is `723523` (I want is `01x0712314`)

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: What do you want exactly, Do you want the address as hex?

Comment: Try `long.ToString("X");`.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I want get handle of control

Comment: @donggas90 i did, and result nearly with base value. 
base value is 0x000704de, after ToString("X"), value is 704DE